# Xcode 5 says "Simulator in Use" when running 64-bit Unit tests

Tags: 64-bit, ios-simulator, xcode5, sentestingkit

I just downloaded and installed Xcode 5 GM seed.  I removed the previous Xcode (DP5).  When I open my project, select "iPhone Retina (4-inch 64 bit)" and type Command-U to run my SenTeskingKit unit tests, Xcode invariably complains:

> "Simulator in Use - The Simulator can't be launched because it is already in use."

I have run xcode-select to point to the new Xcode, restarted my MacBookPro, and made sure there are no other iPhone sim processes running under the Activity Monitor.

Answer (score 3):

With Xcode 5 Version 5.0 (5A1413), I cannot run 64-bit unit tests at all. Always gives a "Simulator in use" error alert.

Quitting Xcode or the Simulator does not help.

My "solution", thanks to this question, is to run the tests against the 32-bit simulator.

Comment: Seems to be an Xcode bug still in 5.0.2 :(. Can only run 32-bit unit tests.

Comment: @Adam I have been able to run 64-bit tests on Xcode 5.0.2 (5A3005). See my answer [below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21781010/441735).

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and found the reason.

Testing on the 64-bit Simulator needs **Build Active Architecture Only** to be **YES**.

By default this setting is **YES** for **Debug** and **NO** for **Release**:

[image: Build Active Architecture settings]

So check the Scheme settings and set **Debug** configuration for **Test** action:

[image]

Alternatively you can test from command line:

```
xcodebuild  -project {project}.xcodeproj -scheme {scheme} -sdk iphonesimulator -destination platform="iOS Simulator",OS=7.0,name="iPhone Retina (4-inch 64-bit)" -configuration Release ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=YES test
```

Comment: For whatever reason, this is not broken anymore (I'm running xcode 5.0 - 5A1412) - it works with, or without, setting BAA to YES.

Comment: Nice workaround. 90% of my unit-testing is for libraries - and it's very dangerous to have "build for active architecture only" set to an incorrect value (YES) - too easy to forget before committing! Hopefully Apple will fix the bug instead :). @Rayfleck 5.0 has many bugs, we had to switch to 5.0.2-preview to workaround some - but 5.0.2 has new bugs :(. Eagerly awaiting the next release.

Answer (score 0):

I get this all the time and the only thing that seems to guarantee to fix it is restarting both Xcode and the Simulator.  Sorry I don't have a better answer.

EDIT: Sometimes just changing device (e.g. from iPhone to iPad or from retina to non-retina) is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Simply click on Quit Xcode from the editor menu of Xcode and open Xcode again.  You will get the simulator.